# Python 3d plot - axis centered

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, plotly

I'm trying to make a 3d plot in python with axis in the middle like so:

[image]

I've tried with matplotlib and plotly without success. Just to specify my problem, i don't want a plot like the following image, where you can see the axis are outside the data:

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for.? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442713/move-spines-in-matplotlib-3d-plot

Comment: @user3747724 Be specific, `plotly` or `matplotlib`??

Comment: Thanks guys! @AshSharma not quite - the axis has to be in origo as i tried to show with the image. Maybe this is an better image: https://www.intmath.com/blog/wp-content/images/2014/11/geogebra-coordinates.png

Comment: @NarenMurali it doesn't matter, just the one where it is possible to do this :D

Comment: @user3747724 the answer in that link says it is not possible to move the axes within matplotlib for 3D plots. Although it is quite possible to do what you're looking for in 2D plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this either, so this is my work around:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal') 

# Draw centered axes
val = [1,0,0]
labels = ['x', 'y', 'z']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for v in range(3):
    x = [val[v-0], -val[v-0]]
    y = [val[v-1], -val[v-1]]
    z = [val[v-2], -val[v-2]]
    ax.plot(x,y,z,'k-', linewidth=1)
    ax.text(val[v-0], val[v-1], val[v-2], labels[v], color=colors[v], fontsize=20)


# Hide everything else
# Hide axes ticks
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])
# make the panes transparent
ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
# Hide box axes
ax._axis3don = False

# Expand to remove white space
ax.set_xlim(np.array([-1,1])*.57)
ax.set_ylim(np.array([-1,1])*.57)
ax.set_zlim(np.array([-1,1])*.57)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]