# Is there a better way to plot orthogonal axes using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Ahoy!

I am trying to plot vectors in 3D using the matplotlib `quiver` function. To help visualize them, I also would like to plot orthogonal axes centered at the origin.

Ideally, I would like to move the so-called spines, but according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442713/move-spines-in-matplotlib-3d-plot), there is no easy fix for that.

I ended up plotting the axes as three vectors along x, y & z (see my code below), but I can't help but think this is a terrible solution... Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

f = plt.figure(1)
ax=plt.gca()
soa = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
X, Y, Z, U, V, W = zip(*soa)
soa2 = np.array([[0,0,0,np.sqrt(2)/2,np.sqrt(2)/2,np.sqrt(2)/2]])
I, J, K, F, G, H = zip(*soa2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, color='black')
ax.quiver(I, J, K, F, G, H)
ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])
f.show()
```

And here's the image returned by this script:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather not use `quiver` because it **doesn't** handle *float128* dtypes properly for its input arguments `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `U`, `V`, and `W`. In fact, it silently converts these inputs to *float*, which is usually *float64* in our systems. As a result, *float128* inputs result in overflow!

Instead, I'd like to use [CT Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487184/ct-zhu)'s brief class `Arrow3D` in [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22867877/4526384). It works flawlessly with *float128* coordinates and provides various *arrow styles*.

With that help, I developed this function to draw X, Y, and Z axes at a graph center:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from Arrow3D import Arrow3D


def draw_xyz_axes_at_center(mpl_ax):

    # Compute max_lim based on plotted data
    x_lim = abs(max(mpl_ax.get_xlim(), key=abs))
    y_lim = abs(max(mpl_ax.get_ylim(), key=abs))
    z_lim = abs(max(mpl_ax.get_zlim(), key=abs))
    max_lim = max(x_lim, y_lim, z_lim)

    # Position xyz axes at the center
    mpl_ax.set_xlim(-max_lim, max_lim)
    mpl_ax.set_ylim(-max_lim, max_lim)
    mpl_ax.set_zlim(-max_lim, max_lim)

    # Draw xyz axes
    axes = ['x', 'y', 'z']
    for i, axis in enumerate(axes):
        start_end_pts = np.zeros((3, 2))
        start_end_pts[i] = [-max_lim, max_lim]

        # Draw axis
        xs, ys, zs = start_end_pts[0], start_end_pts[1], start_end_pts[2]

        a = Arrow3D(xs, ys, zs, 
                    mutation_scale=20, arrowstyle='-|>', color='black')
        mpl_ax.add_artist(a)

        # Add label
        end_pt_with_padding = start_end_pts[:, 1] * 1.1

        mpl_ax.text(*end_pt_with_padding,
                    axis,
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center',
                    color='black')
```

To draw a vector:

```py
def draw_vector(mpl_ax, v):
    xs = [0, v[0]]
    ys = [0, v[1]]
    zs = [0, v[2]]

    a = Arrow3D(xs, ys, zs, 
                mutation_scale=20, arrowstyle='->', color='#1f77b4')
    mpl_ax.add_artist(a)

    # Axes limits automatically include the coordinates of all plotted data
    # but not Arrow3D artists. That's actually why this point is plotted.
    mpl_ax.plot(*v, '.', color='#1f77b4')
```

Let's use them:

```py
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7)).add_subplot(projection='3d')

draw_vector(ax, np.array([2, 3, 5]))

draw_xyz_axes_at_center(ax)

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

I used *Python 3* by the way and didn't test it on *Python 2*.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Shahrokh Bah! This is exactly what I was looking for!