# How to turn on all axes boundaries of a 3D scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, axis, scatterplot3d

How can I turn on all axes lines of a 3D scatterplot? More specifically, how can I make a scatterplot like this:

[image]

Stay like this:

[image]

Comment: Sadly I do not think an easy solution exists for your problem at this time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442713/move-spines-in-matplotlib-3d-plot

Comment: Thank you @JasonChia. That's sad news, though. Do you think I should update my question adding the link you've sent me?